# Check for selected value without having 'selected' keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Can I check which option of the drop-down menu is selected, without having the `selected` keyword in the HTML, even when some value is selected?

This is how the inspected HTML code of the drop-down form looks, when I HAVE already selected one of the options:

```
<form id="dropdown_menu">
  <select id="dropdown_options">
    <option>Choose size</option>
    <option>S</option>
    <option>XL</option>
    <option>XXL</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Or just to check if any option of the menu is selected, at all...

Comment: `var $selected = $("#dropdown_menu").find("option:selected")`.

Comment: it looks or should it look like that??

Comment: how about this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sc4Gj/

Comment: @TJonS `I don't think so.` Why not? The `selected` attribute would only be present if an item is selected when the control loads. The poster's code will correctly show a `select` control with no selected item.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#dropdown_options")[0].selectedIndex` gives you the current index of the selected element.

Without jQuery you can read the value from: `document.getElementById('dropdown_options').selectedIndex`

Here you will find an example:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qm58a/3/